# Phone line activity/status/indicator test equipment

Tags: telephony, test-equipment

I'm working on a software package that operates a landline modem through AT commands. The program snoops Caller Id and kills the call when a telemarketers calls. The program also reports the call to Harassing Call Centers if the caller is known on the FTC [Do Not Call](https://www.ftc.gov/site-information/open-government/data-sets/do-not-call-data) violator list.

As the program is getting more complex I need to know what is happening on the line without Heisenberg-ing the line. For example, the modem may report LINE IN USE when it is really me listening trying to figure out line state.

USB modems don't have external speakers so I can't follow progress. If I pick up an extension and listen to the line then I disturb the state. (I also tried to breadboard a small tap with 1 MΩ pull-up resistor connected to ring and old PC speaker. The best I could describe it is, a half-ass attempt when I really needed a proper solution).

I am looking for some test equipment to report on activity. I need to know when:

- on-hook and off-hook
- dial tone and no dial tone
- call connected
- busy and fast busy
- number not in service
- voice traffic on the line

For example, here are some program states and what I would like to determine for line status:

- program does nothing - sense "on-hook" and "no dial tone"
- program tells modem `ATH1` (go offhook) - sense "off-hook" and "dial tone" or "answer"
- program dials, called party picks up - sense "call connected"
- called party speaks - sense "voice traffic"

Status LEDs are fine for my purposes. I can watch a flashing LED and then pick up an extension to learn how the flashing LED corresponds to tone, like a fast busy or warble. Tester should be self powered so it does not load the line.

I don't require professional equipment; something for power users is fine. Ideally the test equipment will be $50 to $100 USD.

Thanks in advance.

---

Here's why the workflow is tricky when commanding the modem. Suppose you call your home number from your cell phone:

1. program listens
2. program detects RING (ring 1)
3. program detects CALLER ID (Type 1 Caller ID in US)
4. program detects RING (ring 2)
5. program detects RING (ring 3)
6. ...
7. loop back to (1)

Between steps (3) and (4), program can classify and take action. At step (3), program can determine telemarketer and:

1. go off-hook (answer)
2. pause 1.5 seconds
3. go on-hook (hang up)
4. pause 12 seconds
5. call Harassing Call Center (dial)
6. pause 3 seconds
7. go on-hook (hang up)

The pauses are trial and error. Step (2) should wait until call CONNECT.

Step (4) should wait until the line is inactive and circuit is torn down. Step (4) is tricky because the circuit may still be available (not torn down) because cell phones may intermittently drop.

Step (6) should wait until CONNECT and the Harassing Call Center says its message (like "Call trace has been activated").